Estimate $f^{(n)}(a)$ with L1 norm for f holomorphic
$\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a region, $\overline{B(a,r)}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}||z-a|\leqslant r\}\subset\Omega$ $(r>0)$. Suppose $f\in H(\Omega)$, prove the inequality:
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!(n+2)}{2\pi r^{n+2}}\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}.$$
Here $\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}=\int_{\overline{B(a,r)}}|f|dm$, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{C}$.
I tried using Cauchy integration formula:
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z-a|^{n+1}}dz=\frac{n!}{2\pi r^{n+1}}\int_{|z-a|=r}|f(z)|dz,$$
but I don't know the relationship between$\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}$and$\int_{|z-a|=r}|f(z)|dz$ and how I can get $n+2$ on the numerator.

Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3562657/42969

You mean $\int |f(z)|,|dz|$. This is important. My hint to you is to do the double integral over the disk in polar coordinates.

For $0 < \rho < r$ is, using the Cauchy integral formula,
$$
 |f^{(n)}(a)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi \rho^{n+1}}\int_{|z-a|=\rho}|f(z)||dz|
= \frac{n!}{2\pi \rho^{n}} \int_0^{2 \pi} |f(a+\rho e^{i \phi}| \, d\phi \, .
$$
Then
$$
 \rho^{n+1} |f^{(n)}(a)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} |f(a+\rho e^{i \phi}| \, \rho d\phi \, .
$$
Integrating this with respect to $\rho \in (0, r) <$ gives
$$
\frac{r^{n+2}}{n+2 } |f^{(n)}(a)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} |f(a+\rho e^{i \phi}| \, \rho d\phi d\rho = \frac{n!}{2\pi} \Vert f \Vert_{L_1(\overline{B(a, r)})} \, ,
$$
which is the desired estimate.

Well, your answer is quite simpler.

The hint by @Martin R and @Ted Shifrin is useful, and I have a better estimation now.
Fix $\alpha <1$, then for any $\alpha r \leqslant s \leqslant r$,
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi (\alpha r)^{n+1}}\int_{\overline{B(a,s)}}|f(z)||dz|=\frac{n!}{2\pi (\alpha r)^{n+1}}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+se^{it})|sdt.$$
Integrating from $s=\alpha r$ to $s=r$, we have
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi r^{n+2}\alpha^{n+1}(1-\alpha)}\int_{\alpha r}^{r}(\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+se^{it})|sdt)ds.$$
Here$\int_{\alpha r}^{r}(\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+se^{it})|sdt)ds\leqslant\int_0^{r}(\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+se^{it})|sdt)ds=\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}$,
so we have$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi r^{n+2}\alpha^{n+1}(1-\alpha)}\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}.$$
Since this is right for any $\alpha<1$,we can get a better estimation by finding the maximum of $\alpha^{n+1}(1-\alpha)$.
With the use of $a_1a_2...a_k\leqslant(\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_k}{k})^k$, it's easy to get
$$\alpha^{n+1}(1-\alpha)=\frac{1}{n+1}\alpha^{n+1}((n+1)-(n+1)\alpha)\leqslant \frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{n+1}{n+2})^{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+2}},$$
and when $\alpha=n+1-(n+1)\alpha$ or $\alpha=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ we get "=".
Now my previous inequality is quite easy to approach:
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi r^{n+2}}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+2}}\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}\leqslant \frac{n!(n+2)}{2\pi r^{n+2}}\Vert f\Vert_{L1(\overline{B(a,r)})}.$$
